# TextViews Do Not Appear As Expected - Android XML

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

[image]

I'm not sure why this is happening - but several of the TextViews (most of the ones on the right hand side) do not appear - and I cannot seem to identify why. Can anyone spot why this might be happening?

Thanks in advance!

(any suggestions are apprecited)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/download"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_ListView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_ListView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingBottom="65dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/background"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingBottom="65dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_dilemmas"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="646dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_dilemmas" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_locations"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="646dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_locations" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/boxart"
            android:layout_width="450dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/boxart"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="65dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_ListView2a"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingLeft="450dp" >
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/timeline_bottom_android"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backbtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_back_arrow" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/backButtonTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/saveButton"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Movies"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="646dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_music_top_center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_plotinfo"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="646dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="310dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_plotinfo" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_quotes"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="646dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="410dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_quotes" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_recipe"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="646dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="510dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_recipe" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_shopping"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="946dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_shopping" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_superfan"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="946dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_superfan" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/icon_trivia"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="946dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_trivia" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_vehicles_top_center"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="946dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="310dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_vehicles_top_center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_weapons_top_center"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="946dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="410dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_weapons_top_center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_who_top_center"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="946dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="510dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_who_top_center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dilemmas"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="746dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Dilemmas"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/locations"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="746dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
            android:text="Locations"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/music"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="746dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
            android:text="Music"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/plot_info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="746dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="310dp"
            android:text="Plot Info"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quotes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="746dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="410dp"
            android:text="Quotes"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/recipes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="746dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="510dp"
            android:text="Recipes"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/shopping"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1046dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Shopping"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/superfan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1046dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:text="SuperFans"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trivia"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1046dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
            android:text="Trivia"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vehicles"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1046dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="320dp"
            android:text="Vehicles"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/weapons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1046dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="420dp"
            android:text="Weapons"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/who"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1046dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="520dp"
            android:text="Who"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is the device size, You know that this layout is not working for a smaller devices right?